# Copying images from the DCIM folder to another folder cause loss of image quality

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-camera-intent, android-bitmap

I am using default camera intent to capture images in my activity. After that I store their path in in an array. At end of activity, I copy the images to my application folder. For some reason the images are not copying in full quality. Ex: If an image in the DCIM folder is 1.04 MB, then it is only a ~2KB in my application folder.

I am using this code in my app. For calling camera intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

In onActivity Result I am doing:

```
Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

Uri tempUri = getImageUri(context, photo);

imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(tempUri);

imagesList.add(imagePath);
```

getImageUri() and getRealPathFromURI() methods are:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
            inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
            null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

At end of my activity, I am using this method to copy images to my application folder:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < noteImagesList.size(); i++) {

        File fileimg = new File(noteImagesList.get(i));

        File newImageFile = new File(parentfolderpath,
                            i+"_newimage.jpg");
                    newImageFile.createNewFile();

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileimg
                            .getAbsolutePath());

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(
                            newImageFile);

        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();

        if (myBitmap != null) {

        if (!myBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            myBitmap.recycle();
        }

        myBitmap = null;
        }


    }
```

After copying, the image is loosing it's quality and size. Where the image in the DCIM folder is sharp and around ~1 MB, after copying it is blurred and around ~1KB.

Could any one tell what I am missing while copying images?

**Edit**

above code works fine if i use it for images select from gallery but still no luck with camera images.

**Edit 2**

i have used this code also but same result.

```
public void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` instead of `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG`

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal same result while using CompressFormat PNG

Comment: why are you doing `inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);` and `ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();` in `getImageUri()`

Comment: `imagesList.add(imagePath);` Please give an example of what imagePath looks like. Isn't it the thumbnail for the image that you have here? And ofcourse never use bitmap factory to copy files.

Comment: i have copied these methods from web and applied.

Comment: That is not an answer to my request. Please tell what the path looks like.

Comment: @greenapps imagePath is String type and above comment was for Sagar Pilkhwal

Comment: I'm not interested in the type. Ofcourse it is a Sting. I want to know the value.

Comment: @greenapps printing "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1410864606688.jpg" in log

Comment: Now take an explorer app (like ES File Explorer) and go to that directory and investigate the file. Is it a thumbnail or the real picture?

Comment: @greenapps thanks for suggestion, it was my fault the image in folder is thumbnail, and real image is IMG_1410864606688.jpg

Comment: That format is interesting. Which device do you use?

Comment: @greenapps Motorola MotoG

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that if you pass a URI indicating where to write the file, then you will get back the full sized image in the extras data. However, if you don't pass a URI, you get a small version (a thumbnail) back.

Since you are not passing a URI, you are getting the thumbnail, and then saving. / copying that, not the full-size version.